# 2002 Code Error When Trying Import / Export MariaDB Databases in Bitnami's WordPress Multi-tier Stack

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb

I'm trying to do database management via SSH for [Bitnami's WordPress Multi-tier Stack](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MXM8W5Q)/ Specifically I want to export and do an initial import (though I will probably just create a new database).

When I run the following commands, I get the following errors:

---

Command: `mysqldump -u root -p bitnami_wordpress > bitnami_wordpress.sql`

Output: `mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)" when trying to connect`

This also creates an 0B SQL file in my home directory.

---

Command: `mysqladmin -u root -p status` (I enter my password)

Output:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket . 
'/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: 
'/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

---

Command: `cd /opt/bitnami/mariadb/` + `ls`

Output:

```
bin                 CREDITS            include         licenses   README-wsrep
COPYING             data               INSTALL-BINARY  plugin     sbin
COPYING.thirdparty  EXCEPTIONS-CLIENT  lib             README.md  share
```

---

Command: `sudo find . -name mysql`

Output:

```
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.mysql-client/lib/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.mysql-client/lib/handlers/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.libphp/lib/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.libphp/lib/handlers/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.wordpress/lib/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.wordpress/lib/handlers/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.php/lib/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.php/lib/handlers/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.apache/lib/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.apache/lib/handlers/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.mariadb/lib/databases/mysql
./root/.nami/components/com.bitnami.mariadb/lib/handlers/databases/mysql
./opt/bitnami/mysql
./opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql
./opt/bitnami/mariadb/include/mysql
./opt/bitnami/mariadb/include/mysql/server/mysql
./opt/bitnami/mariadb/include/mysql/mysql
./opt/bitnami/mariadb/bin/mysql
./usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysql
```

---

Commands:

```
find /opt/bitnami/mysql/ -name "*.cnf"
```

Output: Nothing

```
find /opt/bitnami/mariadb/ -name "my.cnf"
```

Output:

```
/opt/bitnami/mariadb/share/my-medium.cnf
/opt/bitnami/mariadb/share/my-small.cnf
/opt/bitnami/mariadb/share/my-large.cnf
/opt/bitnami/mariadb/share/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
/opt/bitnami/mariadb/share/my-huge.cnf
/opt/bitnami/mariadb/share/wsrep.cnf
```

---

Command: `nano /opt/bitnami/mariadb/share/my-medium.cnf` *(what's the difference between my-medium, my-small, and my-large)?*

Output:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MariaDB clients
[client]
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock
```

NOTE: `/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock` does not exist.

---

I've poked around a bit and came across [MariaDB's Documentation about 2002 errors](https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001215603-ERROR-2002-HY000-Can-t-connect-to-local-MySQL-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-), but I don't seem to have the same .conf file (nor do I know where to look)

...from here I have no idea where to go, I've only done limited database management via shell.

**Concise questions:**

1. **How do I export my database without getting the [2002 error](https://help.memsql.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001215603-ERROR-2002-HY000-Can-t-connect-to-local-MySQL-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-)?**
2. **How do I overwrite / update my database?**

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The folks at Bitnami came through. I was connecting to the wrong host.

Find the host:
`sudo cat /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php | grep 'DB_HOST'`

To export:

`mysqldump -h provisioner-peer -u root -p bitnami_wordpress > bitnami_wordpress.sql`